# Factorization of conditional expectation

Tags: statistics

I have to proof this. And I have no idea how to do it.

Let (X,U) and (Y,V) independent random vectors, s.t. X and Y are real valued r.v.s with finite expectations. Show that then:

E[X.Y|(U,V)]=E[X|U]E[Y|V]

I would really appreciate it, If any body could also give me an example for it that I would understand this better. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Let's call the event $(U,V)=(H,K) $ as A, the event $U=H$ as B and the event $V=K$ as C, we have:

$E[XY|(U,V)=(H,K)]=E[XY|A]=\frac{E[XY \cdot 1_{A}]}{P(A)}=\frac{E[XY \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C]}{P(B)P(C)}$ because $U,V$ are independent. Then because the two vectors are independent:

$\frac{E[XY \cdot 1_B \cdot 1_C]}{P(B)P(C)}=\frac{E[X \cdot 1_B ]E[Y \cdot 1_C]}{P(B)P(C)}=\frac{E[X \cdot 1_B ]}{P(B)}\frac{E[Y  \cdot 1_C]}{P(C)}=E[X|B]E[Y|C]=E[X|U=H]E[Y|V=K].$ $1_{A}(x)=1, \forall x \in A \; 1_{A}(x)=0, \forall x \notin A.$

Comment: Off-topic. This is confusing conditional expectations in the measure theoretical sense with elementary conditional expectations, by events of positive probability.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i answered to the wrong question or i made some mistakes, i thought that demonstrating that the random variable $E[XY|(U,V)](H,K)$ is equal to the random variable $E[X|U](H)E[Y|V](K)$ for each couple $(H,K)$ of element of the related sigma-algebra would also show that the two random variables are the same. Where did i do wrong?, thanks @Did

Comment: Again, **please check your definitions**. In your comment, $E(X\mid U)(H)$ is undefined since $E(X\mid U)$ is defined on $\Omega$, not on $\mathbb R$. And, in the text of your post, you are liberally dividing by $P(U=H)$ and $P(V=K)$, what happens if these are zero (which is the usual case)?

Comment: Right, i can't divide by 0. Thanks.

Comment: If i define $\sigma((U,V))=\sigma(U) \times \sigma(V)$ then: 
$E[XY|(U,V)]=G$ where $G$ is the $\sigma((U,V))$-measurable function s.t. $E[G 1_A]=E[XY 1_A], \forall A \in \sigma((U,V))$, now $H=E[X|U]$ is $\sigma(U)$-measurable and $J=E[Y|V]$ is $\sigma(V)$-measurable, so $HJ$ seen as a random variable should be $\sigma((U,V))$-measurable. Now i take $(\alpha,\beta) \in \sigma((U,V))$, i have to show that $E[HJ1_{(\alpha,\beta)}]=E[XY1_{(\alpha,\beta)}]$.Thanks to independence $E[HJ1_{(\alpha,\beta)}]=E[H1_{\alpha}J1_{\beta}]=E[E[X|U]1_{\alpha}]E[E[Y|V]1_{\beta}]=E[X1_{\alpha}]E[Y1_{\beta}]$

Comment: Then $E[X1_{\alpha}]E[Y1_{\beta}]=E[XY1_{(\alpha,\beta)}]$ for independence, is this time right? Thanks for your time. @Did

Comment: Again, you cannot define $\sigma((U,V))$ as $\sigma(U)\times\sigma(V)$, even if by $\sigma(U)\times\sigma(V)$, you actually mean the class $C=\{A\cap B\mid (A,B)\in\sigma(U)\times\sigma(V)\}$ (thus $C$ is not $\sigma(U)\times\sigma(V)$) . The class $C$ is a sub-class of $\sigma((U,V))$, but **much smaller**.

Comment: If i have two r.v. $U:\Omega \rightarrow R$ and $V: \Omega' \rightarrow R$  and then take $(U,V) \in \mathbb R^2$ then we have that the sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$ is the borel one which is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $(a,b) \times (a',b'), \forall a,b,a',b' \in \mathbb R $. So we should have $\sigma((U,V))=\{(U,V)^{-1}((a,b)\times(a',b'))\}=\{(U^{-1}(a,b),V^{-1}(a',b'))\}=\{(A,B): A \in \sigma(U),B \in \sigma(V)\}$

Comment: Now i don't get where i'm wrong because i saw that the sigma-algebra of a product space $X_1 \times X_2$ with $(X,\Sigma_1),(Y,\Sigma_2)$ measurable spaces is just $\{B_1 \times B_2: B_1 \in \Sigma_1,B_2 \in \Sigma_2 \}$, which is what i was thinking about when i wrote $\sigma(U) \times \sigma(V).$

Comment: Sorry but **this is completely wrong**. First, the collection of sets in your last comment is not even a sigma-algebra. Second, there is no product involved in your question, where every sigma-algebra is on Omega.

Comment: First major blunder: "If i have two r.v. $U:Ω→R$ and $V:Ω′→R$ and then take $(U,V)∈R^2$" But we never consider this! To begin with, what would be $(U,V)$ if $U$ and $V$ are not defined on the same set $\Omega$? Ad lib.

Comment: *Typo: ...there is no product involved in the question...

Comment: Wouldn't $(U,V)$ be a random vector:$\Omega^*\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, where $\Omega^*=\{(A,B): A \in \Omega, B \in \Omega'\}$? At least i thought that was the case in more dimensions, with events given by all the possible combination of events. I'm slowly understanding: they are not a vector so i should find a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ such that both $U$ and $V$ are measurable.

Comment: Now i see why you thought that i was referring to $C=\{A \cap B| (A,B) \in \sigma(U) \times \sigma(V) \}$ but that's not enough, so maybe $$\sigma(U,V)=\{A: A \in \sigma(U)\} \cup \{B: B \in \sigma(V)\} \cup \{A \cap B: A \in \sigma(U), B \in \sigma(V)\}\cup \{A \cup B: A \in \sigma(U), B \in \sigma(V)\}$$

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent the field, all by yourself? Then, 1. this shows, and 2. you should mention the fact, if only for the sake of unsuspecting readers.

Comment: So we are not just conditioning on both $U,V$? Or maybe is $\sigma(U,V)$ as written above wrong? I tried to make the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that both $U$ and $V$ are measurable with that $\sigma$-algebra, also any function $f(U,V)$ should be measurable too. For sure $C=\{A \cap B, A \in \sigma(U),B \in \sigma(V)\} \subset \sigma(U,V)$. Now i can take the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $C$, $\sigma(C)=\sigma(U,V)$?

Comment: If you have a problem with this notion (and indeed, it seems you have), an option would be to post a question on the site, rather than hijacking someone else's question.